# How are QuantifiedConstraints translated into dictionary passing style?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

`QuantifiedConstraints`<sup>[1](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/QuantifiedConstraints)</sup> has landed in GHC 8.6, I am reading Deriving Type Classes (section 7)<sup>[2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2000/09/derive.pdf)</sup> where it was first suggested. However I can't understand, in operational terms, how `QuantifiedConstraints` are translated into dictionaries. Following is the excerpt from the paper.

```hs
data Rose a = Branch a [(Rose a)]
data GRose f a = GBranch a (f (GRose f a))
class Binary a where
  showBin :: a -> String

-- assuming following exists
-- instance (Binary a) => Binary [a]

instance (Binary a) => Binary (Rose a) where
  showBin (Branch x ts) = showBin x ++ showBin ts 

-- illegal
instance ( Binary a
         , Binary (f (GRose f a))
         ) => Binary (GRose f a) where
   showBin (GBranch x ts) = showBin x ++ showBin ts
```

> What we need is a way to simplify the predicate
> `f (GRose f a)`. The trick is to take the "constant" instance
> declaration that we assumed for `Binary [a]` above, and
> abstract over it:

```hs
-- using QuantifiedConstraints
instance ( Binary a
         , forall b. (Binary b) => Binary (f b)
         ) => Binary (GRose f a) where
  showBin (GBranch x ts) = showBin x ++ showBin ts
```

> Now, as well as `(Binary a)`, the context also contains
> a polymorphic predicate. This predicate can be used to
> reduce the predicate `Binary (f (GRose f a))` to just
> `Binary (GRose f a)`, and we have an instance declaration
> for that.

> Viewed in operational terms, the predicate `(Binary a)`
> in a context corresponds to passing a dictionary for class
> `Binary`. A predicate `forall b. Binary b => Binary (f b)` corresponds
> to passing a dictionary transformer to the function.

In particular I can't grok the following:

1. Reduce the predicate `Binary (f (GRose f a))` to just  `Binary (GRose f a)`
2. A predicate corresponds to passing a dictionary transformer to the function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For regular constraints, the translation maps

```
class Colored a where
   isRed :: a -> Bool

foo :: Colored a => T
```

to

```
newtype ColoredDict a = CD (a -> Bool)

foo :: ColoredDict a -> T
```

Similarly,

```
bar :: (forall a. Colored a => Colored [a]) => U
```

can be translated as

```
bar :: (forall a. ColoredDict a -> ColoredDict [a]) -> U
```

> 2) A predicate corresponds to passing a dictionary transformer to the 
>   function.

The first argument of `bar` is the "dictionary transformer" the OP mentions.

`bar` involves a rank-2 type, but Haskell has been using these for a long time.

> 1) Reduce the predicate `Binary (f (GRose f a))` to just  `Binary
>   (GRose f a)`

The point is: every time `bar` need to resolve a constraint `Colored [t]`, it can exploit the quantified constraint and instead try to resolve the simpler constraint `Colored a`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one more question, can you elaborate on what polymorphic function will the compiler pass into "bar" function in the call-site.

Comment: @zeronone An instance `instance Colored a => Colored [a]` essentially describe how to implement the methods for `[a]`, given those for `a`, for all possible types `a`. This is, essentially, the polymorphic function between the two dictionaries